# Difference in navigation transition in Flutter compared to "stock" Android

Tags: flutter

Compare the following transitions when navigating between routes.

- Flutter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdtyg.jpg
- Android: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lw4e.jpg

You can see one clear difference with the transitions. The pages are pulled over and back on each other when navigated between them.  The style I prefer is this one and not the one that Flutter uses.

Is this a bug or has this transition been changed deliberately?

I use the following code to navigate:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Navigation Transition'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Navigate'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(
                          title: Text('Navigation Transition'),
                        ),
                        body: Center(
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            child: Text('Navigate'),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                ),
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the apps theme data as follows solved the problem:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Navigation transitions',
      theme: ThemeData(
        pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
          builders: const {
            TargetPlatform.android: OpenUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
          },
        ),
      ),
  ....
  }
```

More information regarding the transitions during route changes:

- [MaterialPageRoute.class Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute-class.html)
- [PageTransitionsTheme.class Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PageTransitionsTheme-class.html)
- [Navigator.class Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)